# Oracle Function calling

Tags: php, oracle

I am having problem with Oracle. Can any one please help me? I need to call a function,which is under a package. But i don't know, how to call this function under this package. Your help is highly requested.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS
  FUNCTION MyFunction(Param1 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
END MY_PACKAGE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS
  FUNCTION MyFunction(Param1 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN Param1;
  END;
END MY_PACKAGE;
/


-- using function in SQL
select MY_PACKAGE.MyFunction(123) as val
   from dual
/


-- using function in PL/SQL
declare 
    val_ number;
begin
 val_ := MY_PACKAGE.MyFunction(123);
end;
/
```

PHP is not in my competition, but this code show concept -

```
// as select
$query1 = oci_parse($conn, 'select MY_PACKAGE.MyFunction(:id) as val from dual');
oci_bind_by_name($query1, ":id", $Param1);
oci_execute($query1);

// as anonymous block
$query1 = oci_parse($conn, 'BEGIN :val := MY_PACKAGE.MyFunction(:id); END;');
oci_bind_by_name($query1,':id',$id);
oci_bind_by_name($query1,':val',$val);
oci_execute($query1);
```